# Copying django users from one project to another project

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I am designing the tools for our organization.
Previously I have designed the one tool in which all the users have been registered.Now I am designing the new tool in which I want to copy all the users from the previous tool to this new tool so that there is no need for users to register with new tool again.
The copying of the users include all their models and password.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "all their models"?

Comment: Like custom models to store the extra information of the user like address,employee id,team etc.

Comment: copy the model and the table to your new database

Comment: Exprator how to do that?By copying db.sqlite3?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the new app has the same structure, models etc.
Then, you can use `python manage.py dumpdata <app_name>.<model_name> > <file_name>.json`

Then `python manage.py loaddata <path_to_file>`

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this by copying the "db.sqlite3" from old tool to new tool.
Please do point me if there is some better way.